# Is it possible to ake a non-AJAX HTTP POST from Javascript with JSON body to download a file?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-post

We have a web page that shows reports, with a dynamic set of filters.

A user selects a named report and the page gets the valid filters from WebApi as a JSON list. The user can select the filters, which then shows the results in a grid (again via a WebApi call). All fine so far

Now we to allow a download of the data as a file (e.g. Excel) and have hit a problem.

We want to send a HttpPost (but **not** an *AJAX* post) with the JSON filter data, so that the browser downloads a file. We cannot use a JQuery $.ajax or $.post, as the data is returned in a callback, and not as a browser handled download.

We experimented with a  tag and a submit button, but searching StackOverflow suggest this only supports sending data as name-value pairs, rather than a JSON body. Unless you know different?

It seems the simplest method would be to use a  with a single hidden input field, with the contents of the JSON encoded in a hidden control, and then manually deserialize this at the server?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an html form and loop through the object to add as name value pairs to the form.

```
var query = {},
    $form = $("<form>")
    .attr("method", "post")
    .attr("action", 'pathtoservice');

$.each(query, function (name, value) {
    if (typeof (value) === "number" || typeof (value) === "string") {
        $("<input type='hidden'>")
            .attr("name", name)
            .attr("value", value)
            .appendTo($form);
    }
    else if (typeof (value) === "object") {
        $.each(value, function (i, item) {
            $("<input type='hidden'>")
                    .attr("name", name)
                    .attr("value", item)
                    .appendTo($form);
        });
    }
});

$form.appendTo("body");
$form.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the concept. It would work for simple objects, but arrays might present an problem, plus I am not sure how nested objects would work. I think we will have to bite the bullet and serialize the JSON to a string value - this seems the simplest option.